# Neo4j - Filter Properties in MATCH clasue

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can we filter relationship property in MATCH clause?

I have one relationship like this.

```
[:friends] {"ApprovalStatus" : 1, "ApprovalDate" : "01-Apr-2013 10:10:10" }
```

Now I want to filter "ApprovalStatus" property like this.

```
MATCH other-[r:friends.ApprovalStatus = 1]-(mf)-[r1:friends]
```

So, I can get mutual count with ApprovalStatus = 1 only.

Is it possible in cypher?

Answer (score 2):

```
MATCH other-[r:friends]-(mf)-[r1:friends] 
WHERE r.ApprovalStatus=1
```

Comment: That is not fulfill my query. Please check this for more detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878498/neo4j-search-list-with-mutual-count

Comment: Your new post is different from the question above. You asked here about filtering on a relation property and that is what is answered

Comment: Ya, I have property "ApprovalStatus" on relationship, and that I have to filter, as per my understanding. :) Can we chat on gmail for a while to clear this misunderstanding?

Comment: Hello @Luanne, did you get any idea?

Comment: Hi @Luanne, my email id is sapkal.manish@gmail.com, send me your email id, I will send you my data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
MATCH other-[r:friends{ApprovalStatus:1}]-(mf)-[r1:friends]
```

Comment: This was flagged, so I'd add a bit more info.